# The data source is of an invalid type. It must be an IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource. Contains the Foloowing Error When Binding Data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to bind data to my drop-down control. It redirects me back to the catch-block and shows the error:

> The data source is of an invalid type. It must be an IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Edge_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString());
try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT CustomerCode,CustomerName FROM ufn_Fill_SalesOrder_Pending_Dispatch('E','','"+ usr.CmpyCode + "','','') Where SoType = 'F'", con);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FillFor",'E');
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DispatchType", "");
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CmpyCode", usr.CmpyCode);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectCode", "");
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerCode", "");

    //SqlDataReader Reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    //cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader Reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    // Reader = getReader(cmd2)

    if (cmd2 != null)
    {
        ddlCust.TextField = "CustomerName";
        ddlCust.ValueField = "CustomerCode";
        ddlCust.DataSource = cmd2;
        ddlCust.DataBind();
    }
}
catch (Exception ev)
{
    Response.Write(ev.Message.ToString());
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is a typo. You wrote `ddlCust.DataSource = cmd2;`. You meant `ddlCust.DataSource = Reader;`.

Comment: What is The Mesaning Of Typo

Comment: Thanks For The Solution...It Worked And The Dropdown Is Also Working